# mplayer play multiple videos each with -audiofile

Tags: mplayer

I have 10 videos from 01.mkv to 10.mkv and 10 matching external audio tracks. I want to run mplayer to play all videos consecutively, each with matching audio, e.g.:

mplayer 01.mkv -audiofile 01.mka 02.mkv -audiofile 02.mka ...

Is there a way to do it without typing in each video+audio? I need all videos in one command line so I can traverse then using < > buttons.

Comment: I meant consecutively. Will try smplayer. I just like console version more, thought there should be a way for it too.

Comment: The source code will tell you if you can read it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort of solved it with:

```
mplayer $(seq -w 1 10 | xargs -iX echo X.mkv -audiofile X.mka)
```

Yet this won't work when file names have special characters.